# " ; expected " error while setting array value

Tags: c#, arrays

```
string[] aryProp = { "Name", button.Name };
//ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(aryProp);
aryProp={ "Width" , button.Width.ToString() };
```

" ;  expected " (line 3)
Why am I getting this error ?

EDIT:
@jon , @David , @Grant : Thanks for the help ,But why should I use different syntaxes ? Isn't it kinda illogical ?

Comment: Like @GrantWinney said change code as button.Width.ToString();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error ?

Because while your syntax is valid for initialization in a variable declaration, it's *not* valid for a plain assignment. You can use:

```
aryProp = new[] { "Width" , button.Width.ToString() };
```

Or:

```
aryProp = new string[] { "Width" , button.Width.ToString() };
```

In specification terms, `{ ... }` is an *array-initializer* whereas `new string[] { ... }` is an *array-creation-expression* (which includes an *array-initializer*, of course). An *array-initializer* isn't a separate expression you can use as a value; it can only be used in an *array-creation-expression*, a *local-variable-initializer* or a *variable-initializer*.

In non-specification terms: yes, it looks a bit inconsistent, but I suspect there would be significant issues allowing `aryProp = { ... }` everywhere, but it's nice to allow it for declarations...

Comment: @David : You deleted your post , So I couldn't vote it up , anyway thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using 1-dimensional array, in your case I suspect you should use 2-dimensional or Dictionary like that:

```
  var aryProp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  aryProp.Add("Name", button.Name);
  aryProp.Add("Width", button.Width.ToString());

  foreach (var element in aryProp)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(element.Key + " " + element.Value);
  }
```